# 少しとろけ始めた表情 >> What does this face expression mean?

Tags: meaning, expressions, japanese-to-english

I came across a line describing a character face
少しとろけ始めた表情 >> I don't understand this ,my guess is "A little bit relaxed face/expression "?

Comment: Did you understand what 連用形+始める means?

Comment: In line with what @JimmyYang said, 1) make sure you understand what とろける means, 2) make sure you understand what 始める means, 3) make sure you understand how 始める changes the meaning when used as an auxiliary verb in a verb compound.